# How to disable video download on website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a website which consist of many videos.Now i want to disable download video from website so that user can't get it in free.How can I ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop users from downloading video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806908/stop-users-from-downloading-video)

Comment: Please post some code so that somebody will get a clue on what your problem is. Otherwise it is like you're asking people to help you without telling them how to help.

Comment: It is a possible duplicate like mammago said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hard truth you need to know is: if the user can see the video, the user will be able to download or copy the the video in some way.

So there is not a 100% secure method to prevent users to copy your video.

But I think I know what you are trying to accomplish. So some suggestions based in my experience:

**Restrict download from unauthenticated users**

You can avoid not paying users from easily downloading your video files by checking if they are logged in.

The following code checks if the user is logged as a paying customer and sends the video file. If not, it redirects the user to the login page. You can also redirect them to the landing page where he or she can become a paying customer:

```
if(userIsLoggedIn()) {
    var videoData = readVideoData("video.mp4");
    Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
    Response.Write(videoData);
} else {
    Response.Redirect(loginURL);
}
```

**Digital Rights Management**

The best method, and the most expensive one, is to make use [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) (Digital Rights Management). With DRM you have a lot more possibilities to control who can see your video.

This solution requires a lot more experience, cost and infrastructure to be implemented. And your users may not have a smooth experience playing your videos since they will need to download a specific player.