# Prevent permission of sacing the image from htm page

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent user from downloading or saving an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506124/how-to-prevent-user-from-downloading-or-saving-an-image)

how to create a web page that not allow the user to download or save image(contains on the that site) using php,That means i want to create a web page that allows user only viewing the image,not allow the user to save or download the image in php

Answer (score 0):

You can't, if they can see the image in the browser it's already on their PC.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way you can accomplish this.

You can add some javascript code that acts on right clicks (which is really easy to bypass, but it will stop any non-tech-savvy user and annoy everyone). And this method can be bypassed by just saving the whole page. The image is probably already saved to their computer (in the browser cache) when they view it.

Even if you disable browser caching, since it's transferred over the wire, they can just save the request, or look in the HTML source code for the URL and save manually.

Answer (score 0):

you might watermark the images, so they cant be miss-used, but that will decrease style and usability.